# Troubles compiling uigetfile function and importdata ||Matlab

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-compiler

I finished a long Matlab code, that works just perfect in Matlab.
Now I'm trying to compile the app, to use it as an .exe file on other computers.

*relevant code:*

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.CSV','Select the data file');
delimiterIn = ',';
headerlinesIn = 11;
A = importdata(FileName,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn); % A becomes a 1x1 struct containing data, textdata and colheaders
```

the code imports a `.CSV` file.

The `uigetfile` works just fine, as I used `[FileName,PathName]`. But at line 4 `A = importdata(FileName,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);` the code stops working an I get the following Error message:

> Unable to open File.
>
> Error in => name_of_my_program.m line 4

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I can't change much in the code, as the varibales `A.data` and `A.headliners` are used a lot in the code.

Did I use the `importdata` function wrong? Does the `importdata` function not work with compiled apps?

---

`csvread`istead of `importdata` does work, but as mentioned above, I'm looking for a solution, were I don't need to change all the variables in my long code. So the output got to be a `1x1 struct` containing `A.data`, `A.textdata` and `A.colheaders`

---

*I use MATLAB R2017a and the Appliaction Compiler within*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled applicarion is probably not running in the same folder as your input file, so you should update your code to generate the full path filename using [fullfile](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html):

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.CSV','Select the data file');
delimiterIn = ',';
headerlinesIn = 11;
if FileName == 0; return; end
Filename = fullfile ( PathName, FileName );
A = importdata(Filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn); % A becomes a 1x1 struct containing data, textdata and colheaders
```

Comment: if you change `Filename = fullfile ( Pathname, FileName );` to `Filename = fullfile ( PathName, FileName );` (large letter N in PathName) it's perfect!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Done! :)  Didn't spot the capital N... :)